# Can semicolon be used between interrupted quotations?

Tags: punctuation

This is my last question for this week.

Are both sentences punctuated correctly below?

*'It cannot be done,' he said; 'we must give up the task.'* (Can we use a semicolon after 'he said' above, and then resume the quotation with a lowercase 'we'?)

*'It cannot be done,' he said. 'We must give up the task.'* (I'm assuming this is correct as written.)

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen a semicolon there.  Comma, yes.  Semicolon, no.

Comment: If you left out the 'he said', so that it read 'It cannot be done; we must give up the task', would that make sense with a semi-colon?  I tend to think a comma would be sufficient.

Comment: If we had a comma there, it would be a comma splice (methinks).

Comment: No. I'm pretty sure that it'd be a splice.

Comment: It's two independent clauses, so using a comma would be a comma splice. And I'm with Oldcat; I've never seen a semicolon used to break up dialogue like that before. The second version with the period would be more correct, and certainly more recognizable.

Answer (score 2):

The punctuation surrounding quotes, including direct speech, tends to be a compromise. For instance, a comma is used where a full stop might reasonably be expected:

"I need the car today," said Jill.

[Here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-punctuate-quotations-in-statements.html) is the 'rule' for the situation with OP's first version (I think it makes sense):

> When you plop a speaker tag right in the middle of someone’s
>   conversation, make sure that you don’t create a run-on sentence:
>
> Wrong: “When you move a piano, you must be careful,” squeaked Al, “I
>   could have been killed.”
>
> Right: “When you move a piano, you must be
>   careful,” squeaked Al. “I could have been killed.”

So two sentences (the second not needing another speaker tag) rather than a semicolon or comma. The perhaps reasonable-looking use of the semicolon is non-standard.